# Swift Firebase Follow/Unfollow very laggy

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uibutton

Hi I have a unfollow/follow system using firebase, yet it is very laggy. If I tap on the button like 100 times it sometimes switch from follow to unfollow. The data works, but it gets confused because when I am following a user and want to unfollow, it will show follow, yet I need the text to say unfollow to remove the values. The top code is a check to see if the current user is following and sets the button text, and the second code is what sets the data.

**Edit**

I checked my database and what is happening is that it is creating another duplicate value and deleting it at the same time.... Any idea how to fix this?

```
Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in following {
                if value as! String == self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String {
                    self.follow.setTitle("Unfollow", for: .normal)
                    print("You are following the user")
                } else {
                    self.follow.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
                    print("You are not following the user")
                }
            }
        }
    })


@IBAction func followButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let key = ref.child("Businesses").childByAutoId().key



    ref.child("Businesses").child(userID).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (item, value) in following {
                if value as! String == self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String {

                    ref.child("Businesses").child(userID).child("following/\(item)").removeValue()
                    ref.child("Businesses").child(self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String).child("followers/\(item)").removeValue()

                }
            }
        }

        // Follow
        if(self.follow.titleLabel?.text == "Follow") {

            let following = ["following/\(key)" : self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String]
            let followers = ["followers/\(key)" : userID]

            ref.child("Businesses").child(userID).updateChildValues(following as Any as! [AnyHashable : Any])
            ref.child("Businesses").child(self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String).updateChildValues(followers)

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: nevermind got it figured out :)

Comment: can you update your answer pls...